# C++ filesystem: how to remove a file that has a non-constant name

Tags: c++, file, directory, filesystems

I have a function that deletes a file from the folder "settlements" by name.

My code:

```
void delete_settlement(string name){
     std::ostringstream oss;

     oss<<"settlements/"<<name<<".txt";
     string file_name = oss.str();
     std::ifstream file_exists;
        file_exists.open(file_name);

        //Если файл не существует, оповестить об этом пользователя
        if(!file_exists){
           cout << "File doesn't exist, it can not be deleted\n";
            std::ostringstream oss2;
            oss2<<"buffer_settlements/"<<name<<".txt";

        
        }

        else{

        std::filesystem::path tmp = std::filesystem::temp_directory_path();   
         cout << "NAME " << file_name << "\n";
         std::filesystem::path p = file_name;
         std::filesystem::remove(p);
        }

    }
```

I have tried using file_name instead of path instance, but this didn't work either. This code only works if the path is a constant string (i.e. I replace file_name with a constant string). What shall I do in order to implement the function?

I have tried using different ways of expressing the path to the file, but none of them worked. I always get the following runtime error: `[Inferior 1 (process 9408) exited with code 03]`

Comment: how does it not work? What happens when the path is not a constant string?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number, thanks, I added the decription of the error

Comment: File is open when `remove` is called.  Does your OS allow you to delete open files?

Comment: I would certainly close the file before trying to delete it.

Comment: @RichardCritten, thank you very much, it started working when I added a line that closed the file before deleting it.

Comment: If you know about `std::filesystem` and can use it, why don't you use it to create the full path to begin with? And do check for existence as well? There's just no need for the output string stream or the file opening.

Comment: To expand on my comment, begin with changing the function declaration to `void delete_settlement(std::filesystem::path name)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @RichardCritten and @john pointed out, I had to close the file before deleting it.

The solution:

```
void delete_settlement(string name){
     std::ostringstream oss;

     oss<<"settlements/"<<name<<".txt";
     string file_name = oss.str();
     std::ifstream file_exists;
        file_exists.open(file_name);

        //Если файл не существует, оповестить об этом пользователя
        if(!file_exists){
           cout << "File doesn't exist, it can not be deleted\n";
            std::ostringstream oss2;
            oss2<<"buffer_settlements/"<<name<<".txt";

        
        }

        else{
            file_exists.close();

        std::filesystem::path tmp = std::filesystem::temp_directory_path();   
         cout << "NAME " << file_name << "\n";
         std::filesystem::path p = file_name;
         std::filesystem::remove(p);
        }

    }
```